# What is the Vulkan equivalent of the GtkGLArea widget (GTK+)?

Tags: gtk, gtk3, vulkan

Background: I want to write a CAD application. I want to implement all rendering with Vulkan. And I want to use GTK+.

I don't want a (visible) different window for the rendered image of the object.

So I researched and found the [`GtkGLArea`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/unstable/GtkGLArea.html) widget, which seems to do what I want, but for OpenGL.

Is there an equivalent to `GTKGLArea`? If not, is there another way to implement what I'm thinking of?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a [`GdkWindow`](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk4/stable/gdk4-Windows.html) which I believe is behind many Gtk graphic types such as `GtkWindow` and `GtkWidget` and obtainable with [`gtk_*_get_window()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-get-window). `GdkWindow` has [`gdk_window_create_vulkan_context()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk4/stable/gdk4-Windows.html#gdk-window-create-vulkan-context). With [`GdkVulkanContext`](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk4/stable/gdk4-gdkvulkancontext.html#GdkVulkanContext) you can get raw Vulkan types and theoretically should be able to render to with Vulkan.

Comment: this function/method targets Gtk/Gdk 3.90 (a pre 4.0 version) which is in the working (shown as stable though). This being said, the function/method it's not available on the more common Gtk/Gdk 3.22 version.

Comment: @JoséFonte That goes without saying. Vulkan (the spec) was released only 3.2016. Though Vulkan accepts Xlib, XCB or Wayland widgets. Something could be hacked up with the [X Window System Interaction](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-X-Window-System-Interaction.html)

Comment: My comment was just a note. +1 ;)

Comment: The note is important, though: Vulkan support was only added in GTK+ 4. If you want to use Vulkan with GTK+ 3, you'll have to backport the support over yourself. I'm not sure if you can just use Vulkan directly with GTK+ 3 on a backend-by-backend basis using the public APIs (in the same way tegtkgl or whatever it was called does so with pre-3.16 GTK+ 3) or if you'll have to modify GDK itself... I'm also not sure if GTK+ 4 adds a `GtkVulkanArea` or not.

Comment: thank you for these insights. does anybody know if a GtkVulkanArea widget or similar is planned?

Comment: I'll accept this answer, because there doesn't seem to exist a more highlevel approach (yet).

Comment: The links in this answer have bitrotted.

Answer (score 0):

Lol that's simple trick with backend with X11 and `Xlib_Create_Vulkan_Surface()` on Gtk+3 like it works fine with Gtk+4.