# How to draw using Vulkan on gtk4 widget?

Tags: vulkan, gtk4

Is there an example of how to run vulkan commands on a gtk4 widget?

There are some explanations that it can be done by using Gtk OpenGL widget and then to draw on GL Texture. However, I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45191254/1754322

Comment: I've seen this before. In this manner, a window with vulkan context can be created. I need a widget that will be part of my forms rather than a separate window.